# c# convert date from DateTimePicker into String

Tags: c#, string, date, converters, datetimepicker

I try to convert something like this: `"Wednesday, 21. January 2024"` into this: `"03.01.2024"`. How can I do this in c#?

I will use it for a program. There is an `DateTimePicker`and I will convert the output into a `String`.

**Edit:** The original input is in *German*...

thanks Laurin

Comment: Are you just asking how to parse a date from a string in C#?  This looks like a good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I recommend you show your work, this will get downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, note that `21 January` is *Sunday*, not *Wednesday*, let's change `21` to `3` and perform a standard trick: parse `text` into `DateTime` and then format it into desired string representation:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

string text = "Wednesday, 3. January 2024";

var result = DateTime
  .ParseExact(text, "dddd', 'd'. 'MMMM' 'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  .ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If original text is in *German* (*Deutsch* culture, say `de-DE`) it should be

```
Mittwoch, 3. Januar 2024
```

and we have

```
string text = "Mittwoch, 3. Januar 2024";
           
var result = DateTime
  .ParseExact(text, "dddd', 'd'. 'MMMM' 'yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))
  .ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Finally, you can try using current culture (German on your workstation)

```
string text = "Mittwoch, 3. Januar 2024";
           
var result = DateTime
  .ParseExact(text, "dddd', 'd'. 'MMMM' 'yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
  .ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```